# Why does it need a underscore in the loops in Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I can not understand why does it need "_" before another execution within
a loop. 
Here is the code:

```
for i in range(len(X_train)):
       feed = {X: [X_train[i]],y: [y_train[i]]}
        _, loss = sess.run([train_op, cost],feed_dict=feed)
```

I had no problem in running the code, but I have no idea about why it had to place a "_" before the next statement. Anyone knows?

Comment: It's used as a throwaway variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have supplied two inputs, `sess.run` returns two outputs.

A single underscore is often used in Python as a variable name that we don't care about. `_, loss` just means "I don't care about the first output, give me the second one."

Comment: Got it! So if I don't ignore the first output, it could be like this:
for i in range(len(X_train)):
        feed = {X: [X_train[i]],y: [y_train[i]]}
        UU, loss = sess.run([train_op, cost],feed_dict=feed)

Comment: @Willy correct, then the output of `train_op` will be assigned to `UU`